# Evaluating this double integral numerically using NIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to obtain $I$ as a function of $V$, in the following equation

$I = \int\limits_0^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{x+y}}\right) \left(\frac{1}{e^{V-x-y}+1}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\right) dy\ dx$

I want to numerically evaluate the integral so as to get a curve of $I$ versus $V$.

I used the following commands

```
f[v_] := 
  NIntegrate[
    (1/(1 + Exp[x + y])) (1/(Exp[v - x - y] + 1)) (1/Sqrt[y]), 
    {y, 0, 1000000}, {x, 0, 1000000}]

Plot[f[v], {v, 0, 1}]
```

It gives me the error message:

> NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all
>   integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion
>   option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the
>   AccuracyGoal option.

Context - Basically, the integrand is a product of fermi-functions which i am trying to evaluate so as to get current versus voltage relation in a device.

Comment: 1. Use `SetDelayed[]` (`:=`) instead of `Set[]` (`=`) when defining your function. 2. Reduce your function to a single `NIntegrate[]`. Thus: `f[v_] := NIntegrate[(1/(1 + Exp[x + y])) (1/(1 + Exp[v - x - y])) (1/Sqrt[y]), {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}]` Alternatively: `f[v_] := NIntegrate[LogisticSigmoid[x + y - v] LogisticSigmoid[-x - y]/Sqrt[y], {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}]`

Comment: For comparison, the exact integral can be evaluated for `v == 0`, i.e, `Integrate[
 (1/(1 + Exp[x + y])) (1/(Exp[-x - y] + 1)) (1/Sqrt[y]),
 {y, 0, Infinity}, {x, 0, Infinity}]` evaluates to `(-(-1 + Sqrt[2]))*Sqrt[Pi]*Zeta[1/2]` or `1.072154929940191`

Answer (score 1):

One can do the `x` integral analytically:

```
g[v_] = Integrate[
    (1/(1+Exp[x+y])) (1/(Exp[v-x-y]+1)) (1/Sqrt[y]),
    {x, 0, Infinity},
    Assumptions -> y>0 && v>0
]
```

> Log[(E^v + E^y)/(1 + E^y)]/((-1 + E^v) Sqrt[y])

Using the above we can define:

```
f[v_] := NIntegrate[g[v], {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[f[v], {v, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The answer given by a single NIntegrate and your method have orders of magnitude difference.

Comment: @JashanSinghal You should give an example `v` that demonstrates your claim. Perhaps the issue is that you chose to use 1000000 as an upper limit instead of Infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Direct numerical solution is

```
f[v_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[(1/(1 + Exp[x + y])) (1/(Exp[v - x - y] + 1)) (1/Sqrt[y]), {y, 0, Infinity}, {x, 0, Infinity}]

Plot[f[v], {v, 0, 1}]
```

[image]